# Which device amplifies the optical signal in fiber optics?

Tags: communication, optoelectronics

My teacher ask me one question.
How the optical signal or information was transfered in fiber optics communication?

Then i explained it and use the word optical amplifier then teacher ask me what is optical amplifier i said which amplifies optical signal then again which device amplifies the optical signal in fibre optics communication?

I was dump at that moment i dont have the answer for it and i google it then i read about Doped fiber amplifier(DFA) but i didn't get it so can you give me any suggestion to understand it like any website or explain it.

Comment: This should probably move to http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An optical amplifier is essentially an underdriven laser. To make an inexact electronics analogy, think of how you make an oscillator. You create a circuit with gain and feed the output back to the input. To make an amplifier, you create a circuit with gain and don't use any feedback. (please note that any negative feedback you use within your gain circuit is an implementation detail - think "black box" amplifier).

A laser is an oscillator operating at lightwave frequencies. It has a gain medium and mirrors at each end so that the light coming out of the gain medium is reflected back into it - this is the feedback. One of the mirrors is very slightly degraded so that it lets out a small fraction of the light.

An optical amplifier is the same thing, without the mirrors. A light signal goes into a gain medium, is reinforced by energy from the power supply, and is emitted out the other side as an amplified signal.

The most common type is the erbium-doped fibre amplifier. Erbium ions are excited to a high potential by a pump laser. When an excited ion is hit by an incoming signal photon, it emits a matching photon - therefore two signal photons leave the device. That's optical gain, so it can be used as an optical amplifier.

The details of how the amplifiers work is quite complicated but that's the short version.

Comment: ok then what is used to amplify the optical signal in real time fiber optic communication. I mean what decive is used?

Comment: That would be something that provides a gain medium. You can use any material that you can use in a laser, but the most common by far is some kind of chemically doped glass fibre. That's because amplifiers are mostly inserted into fibre-optic circuits, so you want something that's easy to match.

Comment: I added a little bit on erbium amplifiers to the original answer.

Comment: An optical amplifier is not so much an *underdriven* laser as a gain medium without the resonant cavity that would make it lase. That is, the difference between an amplifier and a laser is not how hard you drive it, it's how much feedback there is.